# Microsoft Graph API - "Trending Around" always fails

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am calling the following endpoint;

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/trendingAround`

I have a valid Access Token applied to my request, as I can make calls to the OneDrive endpoints just fine.

However, for "trending around", I always get the following failure;

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "cef71302-25e7-4180-bf25-ce685e609a80",
      "date": "2016-05-22T08:28:07"
    }
  }
}
```

My Azure Active Directory application is a Native Client one with all 40 delegated permissions on the "Microsoft Graph" application granted.

What am I doing wrong making this call? Is there a permission that I've missed. From what I've read in the documentation, all this call requires is the one to read items in site collections.

**Edit:** I have discovered that the following (very similar) call works as intended;

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/people`

I get the people related to me in my organization back correctly from this. So, what am I missing about "trendingAround"? The only thing I could possibly think of is the Azure AD App permissions, but like I said.. I've given it *everything*...

**Edit 2:** Just to experiment, I removed all permissions from my Azure AD Native Client application in the portal - and the `beta/me/people` call still works! This should at least require `Read users' relevant people lists(preview)` according to the Permission Scopes documentation.

Can anyone enlighten me as to how these permissions are supposed to work, because I'm totally confused.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that my approach of "Grant all the permissions" was misguided. Under the "Windows Azure Active Directory" application, I had granted "Read Directory Data".

The portal did complain that I didn't have permission to do this, but when I refreshed the page it was ticked anyway, so I just assumed that it had been a blip.

Upon creating a totally new Native Client Application, I noticed that the only permission requested under AD by default was "Sign in and read user profile". I changed my original native client's settings to match and... bingo, everything works.

As to why this misconfiguration would have resulted in "trendingAround" failing, I can only guess. I assume that on some level there is a check along the lines of "Has this app been granted Permission X? It has - great! Let's make a call for information on that understanding" and then the whole call just falls apart because the user doesn't really have those rights.